# terraform variable declaration errors

Tags: terraform

i am on terraform 0.11.14, i have an aws_cloudformation_stack resource as below:

````
resource "aws_cloudformation_stack" "ingress_sg" {
  name = "bastion-${var.accountName}-ingressIntuitIPs"

  lifecycle {
    prevent_destroy = true
  }

  parameters {
    VpcId = "${var.default_vpc_id}"
    Port = 22
    Name = "bastion-${var.accountName}-ingressIntuitIPs"
    GroupName = "true"
  }
  }```

when i run terraform, its throwing this error:

```Error: module.swimlane.module.bastion.aws_cloudformation_stack.ingress_sg: 1 error occurred:
    * module.swimlane.module.bastion.aws_cloudformation_stack.ingress_sg: invalid variable syntax: "VpcId". Did you mean 'var.VpcId'? If this is part of inline `template` parameter
then you must escape the interpolation with two dollar signs. For
example: ${a} becomes $${a}.
````

Any help is appreciated. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The error message explains exactly what you need to do:

```
"you must escape the interpolation with two dollar signs. For
example: ${a} becomes $${a}."
```

Means that

```
VpcId = "${var.default_vpc_id}"
```

becomes

```
VpcId = "$${var.default_vpc_id}"
```

Comment: `Note: If you specify the template as a literal string instead of loading a file, the inline template must use double dollar signs (like $${hello}) to prevent Terraform from interpolating values from the configuration into the string. This is because template_file creates its own instance of the interpolation system, with values provided by its nested vars block instead of by the surrounding scope of the configuration`

Comment: @ChrisFNZ: i should have mentioned that i did try with the double dollar sign like you have mentioned, but was of no use. Ran into the same error

Answer (score 0):

adding the extra dollar sign in the template body, as below fixed the issue:

`template_body = <<STACK ..Outputs: SecurityGroupId: Condition: CreateSecurityGroup Export: Name: !Sub $${VpcId}:$${Name}-tcp-$${Port}:id Value: !Ref SecurityGroup STACK }`